# Old Laptop: Kubuntu 18.04 not working. LUBUNTU and XUBUNTU are fine

Tags: kubuntu, 18.04

Kubuntu 18.04 will not boot. Installation works well. After Grub it never gives the greeter.  Plasma never loads.  I get the mouse only.

18.04 Lubuntu and Xubuntu work perfectly. Nice work teams.
I have a 13 year old Toshiba laptop. TECRA A2 Pentium M 32 bit. 1 GB Ram 1500 Mhz.

I have also tried installing kubuntu-desktop (on L and X buntu) and at the greeter I can choose Plasma.  But same thing. I get a mouse and no desktop.

This is not mission critical as you can imagine but if anyone has any ideas I would appreciate it.

Comment: @HattinGokbori87 You should turn your comment into an answer. You might also find an official statement from kde about the need for hardware 3d acceleration, and that would cover it.

Comment: Thanks @chaskes .  I will stick with Xubuntu which runs and is more customizable than Lubunt (from my limited experience)

Comment: How do I mark this as "Solved"

Comment: After a period of time, a check box will appear next to the answer. Check it to mark the answer as accepted (and therefore solved).

Answer (score 2):

I think your question contains the answer. Kubuntu (KDE Plasma) won't run on this 13 year old hardware. Plus 1GB RAM less than the minimum amount. You may try [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/) which is built with old hardware in mind. Or a bit polished and customizable [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/) should also run on old hardware. You may also get lucky with [Ubuntu Mate](https://ubuntu-mate.org/).

Comment: Thanks so much.  That is what I suspected.  I just wondered if there was a workaround.  All the other computers at the school where I work are on Kubuntu so wanted that for similarity.